# Get id and set it as a condition on IF for loading Progress-Bar

Tags: javascript, html, css, bootstrap-4

Okey, so my problem here is... Got a ProgressBar and want it to load.
Now I have achieved that, after i came with the idea why don't I take an ID from HTML and put it as CONDITION on IF Statement for loading the bar.

Im fighting for a week now on how to make this, but no success... there is something that i cant see... something but still cant reach there yet. Its 2 Months on Javascript so don't PhD phrase to much :)

I tried with getAtribute, .value from some id with for loop, but that is just over thinking. Some array [i] should be able to do this. Or?

```html
<div class="progress">
  <div class="progress-bar" id="html" role="progressbar" style="width: 0%;">0/10</div>
</div>
<br><br>
CSS
<div class="progress">
  <div class="progress-bar" id="css" role="progressbar" style="width: 0%;" >0/10</div>
</div>
<br><br>
Javascript
<div class="progress">
  <div class="progress-bar" id="javascript" role="progressbar" style="width: 0%;">0/10</div>
</div>
<br><br>
Visual Studio
<div class="progress">
  <div class="progress-bar" id="visual_st" role="progressbar" style="width: 0%;">6/10</div>
</div>
<br><br>
SQL
<div class="progress">
  <div class="progress-bar" id="sql" role="progressbar" style="width: 0%;">7/10</div>
</div>
</div>
</div>
```

```
// this javascript works 
function () {
  var bar = document.getElementsByClassName("progress-bar");         
  if (bar.width() >= 500) {
    clearInterval(progress);
  } else {
    bar.width(bar.width() + 100);
  }
}
```

and now the part that I cant do, now I was trying the switch statement.

```
function () {
  var bar = document.getElementsByClassName("progress-bar");
  var x = document.getElementsByClassName("progress-bar")[a].getAttribute("id");

  switch (x[a]){
    case 'html':
      if (bar.width() >= 500) {
        clearInterval(progress);
      } else {
        bar.width(bar.width() + 100);
      }
      break;
    default:
      break;
  }
}
```

Comment: `getElementsByClassName("progress-   bar")` has spaces within it. "progress-   bar" is a string : `'xx'` is not the same as `'x x'` or `'x   x'`. Also, what is `a` - where is it defined? Also `elem.getAttribute("id")` will return a string, so `x[index]` will return the character/letter within that string at that index - aka it will return a single letter.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Let's point a few things out, as it will help you the most in understanding some key issues with your code:

```
function () { // no function name

  var bar = document.getElementsByClassName("progress-bar"); 
  // 'bar' is a generic term, alonside 'foo', might want to use something like 'progressBar'
  // also, document.getElementsByClassName() returns a HTML Collection - somewhat like an array
  // bar.width() will not work, as you are not applying it to an element, but to an array

  var x = document.getElementsByClassName("progress-bar")[a].getAttribute("id");
  // 'a' is not defined - it shouldbe an index of some sort
  // if it were to work it would return a string - the value of the id itself
  // the id is not meant to be used as such - better use a 'data-attribute' instead

  switch (x[a]){ 
  // x is a string, as mentioned above
  // x[index] will return the letter within the string, at that index;
  // example: 'mystring'[3] - will give you 't', the 4th letter
  // the same result is for: var z ='mystring'; z[3] - will give you 't', the 4th letter
  // x[a] will never return 'html' - as it is a single letter

    case 'html':
    // this will never run - as x[a] returns a single letter/digit 
    // you cannot write 'HTML' with only one letter/digit :)

      // as mentioned above, bar is a HTML Collection, not an element - bar.width() will not work
      if (bar.width() >= 500) {
        clearInterval(progress); 
        // progress is not defined within your posted code, just saying for future posts 
      } else {
        bar.width(bar.width() + 100);
      }
      break;

      // Also, a micro-optimization: you are getting bar.width() twice
      // store it and use the stored value instead of checking it again, just to get the same result

      // long story short, you could change it with :
      // var currentWidth = bar.width();
      // if (currentWidth >= 500) {
      //   clearInterval(progress);
      // } else {
      //   bar.width(currentWidth + 100);
      // }
      // break;

    default:
      // as there is only one case (if x[a]==='html') - which never runs, then the 'default' will always run
      // the 'default' has no code within it - so it will always run .. no code
      break;
  }
};
```

Closer to a working function would be :

```
function (myIndex) {
  var allProgressBars = document.getElementsByClassName("progress-bar");
  var targetProgressBar = allProgressBars[myIndex];
  var targetIdValue = targetProgressBar.getAttribute("id");
  var currentWidth = targetProgressBar.width();

  switch (targetIdValue){

    case 'html':
      if (currentWidth >= 500) {
        clearInterval(progress); // still need to define 'progress' 
      } else {
        bar.width(currentWidth + 100);
      }
      break;

    default:
      break;
  }
};
```

Closer to a working function + even better :

Change:

```
<div class="progress-bar" id="html" ...>
```

To :

```
<div class="progress-bar" data-value="html" ...>
```

---

```
function (myIndex) {
  var allProgressBars = document.getElementsByClassName("progress-bar");
  var targetProgressBar = allProgressBars[myIndex];
  var targetValue = targetProgressBar.getAttribute("data-value");
  var currentWidth = targetProgressBar.width();

  switch (targetValue){

    case 'html':
      if (currentWidth >= 500) {
        clearInterval(progress); // still need to define 'progress' 
      } else {
        bar.width(currentWidth + 100);
      }
      break;

    default:
      break;
  }
};
```

Best of luck! :)

Comment: Thanks for the explanation. I got other code that is running before this one... scroolEvent. The progress that needs explanation can be switched with "allProgressBars" since the width is fro that.

Answer (score 0):

```
function pipi(type) {
    switch (type) {
        case 'html':
            var bar = $('#html');

            if ($(bar).width() >= 500) {
                clearInterval(progress);
            } else {
                $(bar).width(bar.width() + 100);
            }
            break;

         default:
         break;
   }
}

pipi('html')
```